# XCode console: WARNING! Sole personality is ambiguous; this may lead to erradic behavior - in Keyboard Extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, custom-keyboard

I am have iOS app that consist of custom keyboard extension and its container app. When I try to debug the custom keyboard extension I get the following, rather disturbing log in the XCode console:

```
EasyType Keyboard[84937:5754706] [lifecycle] [u 9061FF85-F4D2-401A-94C2-73377E20E419] [com.easytype.EasyType.Keyboard(1.7.1)] WARNING! Sole personality is ambiguous; this may lead to erradic behavior; personalities: {
    "com.easytype.EasyType.Keyboard" =     {
        685 = "<PKServicePersonality: 0x283175340; core = <PKPlugInCore: 0x283175340; uuid = [9061FF85-F4D2-401A-94C2-73377E20E419], identifier = [com.easytype.EasyType.Keyboard(1.7.1)], isAppExtension = 1, onSystemVolume = 0, containingBundle = [(null)], lastModified = 0, discoveryInstanceUUID = [(null)], path = [/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/762C0B3C-A600-4AB4-AB84-AB2019FA053C/EasyType.app/PlugIns/EasyType Keyboard.appex]>, host pid = 685>";
        84881 = "<PKServicePersonality: 0x2831782a0; core = <PKPlugInCore: 0x2831782a0; uuid = [DAEEF528-9AB6-4482-95E9-03E6BB353BBD], identifier = [com.easytype.EasyType.Keyboard(1.7.1)], isAppExtension = 1, onSystemVolume = 0, containingBundle = [(null)], lastModified = 0, discoveryInstanceUUID = [(null)], path = [/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/762C0B3C-A600-4AB4-AB84-AB2019FA053C/EasyType.app/PlugIns/EasyType Keyboard.appex]>, host pid = 84881>";
    };
}
```

`com.easytype.EasyType.Keyboard` is bundle ID of the keyboard extension. The project was dormant for a while, this log started to show when I started work on it again. How can I fix this?

---

**EDIT**

There also another version of the log, that appears above the more common log sometimes:

```
EasyType Keyboard[85190:5767015] [lifecycle] WARNING! Sole personality requested when nil; THIS MAY BE A SPURIOUS LAUNCH OF THE PLUGIN due to a message to an XPC endpoint other than the main service endpoint; personalities: {
    "com.easytype.EasyType.Keyboard" =     {
        79474 = "<PKServicePersonality: 0x2828c0700; core = <PKPlugInCore: 0x2828c0700; uuid = [706FFAE3-DC72-4DBB-AC32-C2CFFD0BD992], identifier = [com.easytype.EasyType.Keyboard(1.7.1)], isAppExtension = 1, onSystemVolume = 0, containingBundle = [(null)], lastModified = 0, discoveryInstanceUUID = [(null)], path = [/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/648263C7-603F-458E-AB8D-9109DD2C0D80/EasyType.app/PlugIns/EasyType Keyboard.appex]>, host pid = 79474>";
    };
}
```

Comment: Not an answer but the app developers on a team I'm working with had the same issue. 
Just asked how they resolved it and I'm told that they just kept retrying the build process and it would eventually work. They don't use that plugin but it's likely a bug in WidgetKit.

Answer (score 1):

The warning seems won't causing any problems, just a message to developer.

However, the lifecycle of switching between custom keyboards is something your may need to look after to, especially if there're services that need to load / release.

Here are lifecycles that I documented for someone may need:

**A system level alert is presented(ie, connect to device):**

```
willResignActive => didBecomeActive
```

**Switch to home**

```
willResignActive => viewWillDisappear => viewDidDisappear
```

**Close custom keyboard:**

```
viewWillDisappear => viewDidDisappear => viewWillDisappear => viewDidDisappear => deinit
```

**Switch to other app which not open your custom keyboard:**

```
`willResignActive => viewWillDisappear => viewDidDisappear => deinit`
```

**Switching between apps with opened custom keyboards:**

```
    `willResignActive => [Erratic behavior warning listed] => viewDidLoad
 => viewWillAppear => didBecomeActive => viewWillDisappear => didEnterBackground
 => viewDidDisappear => first keyboard may not deinit`
```